# Agularjs ng-class:remove class if other condition becomes true

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

The question might not be clear but I can't figure out a better question to elaborate. I am trying to highlight a table row using ng-class and using conditions. Below is my code:

```
<tr ng-class="{selectSuccess: selectedRows.indexOf(rowData.entity_id) > -1, 
danger: rowData.total_received < rowData.total_sold, 
info: rowData.total_received > rowData.total_sold}">
```

In my code as you can see there are three conditions and three classes. `danger` and `info` classes are added on page load as they become true but `selectSuccess` which becomes true when I select a row so I need to know if there is any possibility to add important to this `selectSuccess`. I have tried adding important via css but that did not work. Or I need to know if I can make the other condition to false when I click on a row.

Note: If you want I can add the whole code but only need to know if I can toggle the class and that is why provided only the main code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `&& selectedRows.indexOf(rowData.entity_id) == -1` to the danger and info  conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much. Firstly I got confused as to how will this work but I could not figure out the logic. Thanks man.